# Infragistics Ultrawebtree control and Child node check on parent node checking with JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am using the Ultrawebtree with checkbox

If check or uncheck the parent node, subsequently all the child nodes should get checked or unchecked based on the parent node check status. I know this can be done by iterating through all the node items using javascript, but the same have perfor,mance issues when there are 100s of childnodes

So is there any way to set the attribute of all the childnode check property with a single line of statement (preferably using JQuery)

something like

```
$(#treeid).siblings.attr("checked", false) //etc (I am sure this line of code won't work)
```

So my requirement is to replace the javascript method of recursively calling tree node for checking/unchecking with a JQuery statement

I tried to use the setChecked methos as below

```
$("#treeid").setChecked(false)
```

but does not seems to be working..

Answer (score 1):

The mutator version of the `attr` method is quite happy to operate on several elements at once, just come up with a selector or function chain that gives you the elements you want and then call `.attr('checked', 'checked')` on it check them or `.removeAttr('checked')` to uncheck them.

Here's a simple demo:

```
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<hr>
<button id="check">Check</button>
<button id="uncheck">Uncheck</button>
```

and:

```
$('#check').click(function() {
    $(':checkbox').attr('checked', 'checked');
});
$('#uncheck').click(function() {
    $(':checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
});
```

Live version: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/FhnbJ/1/